# Error module.exports mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have this Schema and when I try to export, the mongoose it gives an error.

My Schema:

```js
const mongoose = require('../../config/db');

const AgendaSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

  nome: {type: String},
  adress: {type: String},
  data: {type: Date},
  createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Agenda', AgendaSchema);
```

Error mongoose:

> /home/lais/Documentos/Projetos/Node/flashit/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:55
>   throw new ObjectParameterError(obj, 'obj', 'Document'); ^
>   ObjectParameterError: Parameter "obj" to Document() must be an object,
>   got function (req, res, next) { app.handle(req, res, next) } at new
>   ObjectParameterError
>   (/home/lais/Documentos/Projetos/Node/flashit/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/objectParameter.js:23:11)
>   at model.Document
>   (/home/lais/Documentos/Projetos/Node/flashit/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:55:11)
>   at model.Model
>   (/home/lais/Documentos/Projetos/Node/flashit/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:59:12)
>   at new model
>   (/home/lais/Documentos/Projetos/Node/flashit/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3750:13)
>   at Function.model
>   (/home/lais/Documentos/Projetos/Node/flashit/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3748:16)
>   at Consign.into
>   (/home/lais/Documentos/Projetos/Node/flashit/node_modules/consign/lib/consign.js:239:17)
>   at Object.
>   (/home/lais/Documentos/Projetos/Node/flashit/config/server.js:36:3) at
>   Module._compile (module.js:643:30) at Object.Module._extensions..js
>   (module.js:654:10) at Module.load (module.js:556:32) at tryModuleLoad
>   (module.js:499:12) at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3) at
>   Module.require (module.js:587:17) at require
>   (internal/module.js:11:18) at Object.
>   (/home/lais/Documentos/Projetos/Node/flashit/app.js:2:11) at
>   Module._compile (module.js:643:30) at Object.Module._extensions..js
>   (module.js:654:10) at Module.load (module.js:556:32) at tryModuleLoad
>   (module.js:499:12) at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3) at
>   Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:10) at startup
>   (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)

Obs: If I comment this line: module.exports = mongoose.model('Agenda', AgendaSchema); the error disappears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just have to downgrade to 4.8.5 mongoose version and now it's working.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same problem. there is no problem with your schema. you may not have mentioned your create function properly.

```
Agenda.create({name: "subham" ,adress:"ncsdi"},callbackfunction);
```

I solved the problem by above method.

*Sidenote:* please change the spelling of your `name` in your schema

Comment: { ObjectParameterError: Parameter "obj" to Document() must be an object Mostly caused by parameters passed to mongoose that is NOT an object. try searching your create methods or parameters you sent to them and check if theyre missing {} curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and resolved it changing the structure to create schema.

```
module.exports = () => {
 const AgendaSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   nome: {type: String},
   adress: {type: String},
   data: {type: Date},
   createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
 });

 return mongoose.model('Agenda', AgendaSchema);
}
```